# map function in React app showing only one result

Tags: arrays, json, reactjs, axios

i'm trying to fetch results from a `json link`, like this:

```
state = {
   users: []
};
componentDidMount() {
  this.getUsers();
}
getUsers = () => {
axios
  .get("https://api.racidy.com/livetv/uploads/m-jsonobjfin.json")
  .then(data => this.setState({ users: [JSON.parse(data.data.substring(25))] }))
  .catch(err => {
    console.log(err);
    return null;
  });
};
```

from this code, i can get all the data i need.. but when i try to display the results :

```
render() {
  return (
  <Layout>
    <div>
      {this.state.users.length === 0 ? (
        <div>Loading...</div>
      ) : (
        this.state.users.map((e, i) => {
          return <div key={i}>{e.game[i]['imgGame']}</div>;
        })
      )}
    </div>
   ...
```

The result of 'console.log(this.state.users)' on the render method
[image]

I only get one result.. the first one,

What i'm doing wrong?

Comment: please show us the value when you `console.log(this.state.users)` in the render method

Comment: also just a side note about your code, don't use variable names like `i` or `e`. these are not descriptive they are hard to read and add an unnecessary level of complexity. Also dont use index as a key since it changes any time the order changes.

Comment: its showing all the values

Comment: @JoeLloyd i added  a screenshot of the result : https://i.stack.imgur.com/u7BqN.png

Comment: @techipank the problem solved i had to use : `this.state.users[0].game.map`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're iterating users, that only has one element `"game"`.

You should iterate `"game"` instead.

```
render() {
  return (
  <Layout>
    <div>
      {this.state.users.length === 0 ? (
        <div>Loading...</div>
      ) : (
        this.state.users[0].game.map((e, i) => {
          return <div key={i}>{e['imgGame']}</div>;
        })
      )}
    </div>
   ...
```

Comment: i get error:"TypeError: Cannot read property 'map' of undefined"

Comment: Can you provide the result of `console.log(this.state.users)` on the `render` method?

Comment: you need `this.state.users[0].game.map` if i see the data correctly