# Why when I map a fetched array with ReactJs it only displays one result, when it brings all the results?

Tags: reactjs

I'm fetching data from an endpoint, and if I use a `console.log(data)` it shows it correctly.

[Image of my array](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CdmD4.png)

I only want `data.data`, so I use `console.log(data.data)` and apparently It show correctly what I need.

[Data that I need](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0Ei0M.png)

My problem is that I'm trying to show all clients in a table, but it only shows one of them.

This is my code:

```
import { useEffect, useState } from "react";

function Activity() {
  function LoadActivity() {
      fetch("https://localhost:7079/client/listClient")
      .then((response) => {
        return response.json()
      })
      .then((data) => {
        setActivity([data.data])
      });
  }

  const [actividad, setActivity] = useState([]);  
  useEffect(() => {
    LoadActivity();
  }, []);

  return (
    <div>
      <h1>Cliente</h1>
      <table>
        <thead>
          <tr>
            <th>Id</th>
            <th>name</th>
            <th>Email</th>
          </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
          {
            actividad.map((client, i )=>(
              <tr key={client[i].id}>
                <td>{client[i].name}</td>
                <td>{client[i].Email}</td>
                <td>{client[i].id}</td>
              </tr>
            ))
          }
        </tbody>
      </table>
      
    </div>
  );
}

export default Activity;
```

And this is how it displays:

[What is displayed](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5EUv7.png)

I tried to do it like [this question 3 years ago](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57307269/map-function-in-react-app-showing-only-one-result).

I'm very new with React, and I don't know what I'm missing.

Comment: `map` expects a function taking each item being mapped and an optional index. You’re using the index to access each item as an array, which your data  image indicates is incorrect (the data should be posted as formatted text, not a link to an image). The data has neither `name` nor `Email` attributes—you should access properties that exist.

Comment: I’d recommend taking a step back and getting a better handle on what your data is, what its shape is, and use more logging or the debugger.

Comment: why you say is a link to an image? There are not images here, only `srings` that I'm trying to show them in a `<td>`

Comment: he is talking about the image that you have imported in you question

Comment: `setActivity([data.data])` sets `activity` to be an array with one element. If `data.data` is an array, `setActivity(data.data)` and change your map to *not* index into the element.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is how I resolved it

```
 const [equipo, setEquipo] = useState([]);

  useEffect(() => {
    obtenerDatos();
  }, []);

  const obtenerDatos = async () =>{
    const datos = await fetch('https://localhost:7079/cliente/listarClientes')
    const clientes = await datos.json()
    setEquipo(clientes.data)
  }
```